# How to add AWS DAX in Ionic/Cordova App

Tags: cordova, amazon-web-services, ionic-framework

Is it possible to add AWS Java sdk in ionic1 or Cordova app for adding AWS DAX ?

Please check below url of the AWS DAX:

http://docs.aws.amazon.com/amazondynamodb/latest/developerguide/DAX.client.modify-your-app.html

Answer (score 0):

Sure, but you will have to create your own cordova-plugin for it as there is no existing one (at least I could not find one). The SDK is available as `.jar` as I understood from your link so you will probably be interested in the [`<lib-file />` tag](http://cordova.apache.org/docs/en/latest/guide/platforms/android/plugin.html#adding-dependency-libraries) for linking it in the `plugin.xml` of your plugin.

In the `.java` file(s) of your plugin you can then import the classes of the SDK and implement the needed functionality. Finally you have to create a `.js` file which is the interface for your plugin. But have a look at the [Plugin Development Guide](https://cordova.apache.org/docs/en/7.x/guide/hybrid/plugins/index.html) where everything is explained in detail.

I hope this helps to get started, have fun implementing!